# Start task according to bandwith speed?

Tags: router, scheduled-tasks, bandwidth

How I can start task according to my downloading speed "Bandwidth". Lets say I want to start .bat file if my downloading speed didn't exceed 50 KB/s for more than 50 seconds.
What tools should I have.

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: [Obtaining net speed through cmd (Windows)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7376778) might get you started.

Comment: Thanks for this very much, But I will need more than this script, I tried it and it works well and get my router speed but I don't know what should I do next - I don't know much about scripted - . your help will be much appreciated